# Execute function for every subfolder

Tags: linux, bash

I have a folder named students_projects that contains 10 subfolders. Each subfolder has project1.c and project2.c, each one prints a value. I made a bash script function that check those numbers and save them to a txt file. I tested it with 2 .c files named project1 and project2 in Desktop and not in the folder. I made sure that i worked fine but when i went to run it for all the subfolders it keeps saving the values that are in desktop files.

My function:

```
function test () {
  gcc project1.c
  p1=$(./a.out)
  if (( $p1 == 20 ));
  then
    v1=30
  else
    v1=0
  fi
  gcc project2.c
  p2=$(./a.out)
  if (($p2 == 10 ));
  then
    v2=70
  else
    v2=0
  fi
  sum=$(( $v1 + $v2 ))
  on="cut -d' ' -f1 report.txt"
  onoma=$(eval "$on")
  temp="cut -d' ' -f2 report.txt"
  am=$(eval "$temp")
  printf "$onoma $am project1: $v1 project2: $v2 total_grade: $sum\n" >> grades.txt
}
```

Then i do

```
for FILE in students_projects/* ; do
  test
done
```

Comment: The loop you use outside of your function (`for FILE in students_projects/* ; do`) merely sets the variable `FILE` to a filename which matched your glob (`students_projects/*`); but you never appear to use that variable. My guess is you either expected your loop to switch to the directory (in which case you're missing `cd "${FILE}";` in there, or you want to use `${FILE}` inside your function as a prefix for most of your filenames (eg `gcc "${FILE}/project1.c"` and others).

Comment: I would also add, that it is recommend to use the `find` utility for scripts such as these (although that isn't necessarily related to the problem here).

Comment: Use of `cut` and `eval` is not necessary here.  You can just use `set -- $var` with globbing disabled (`set -f`) or use `read -ra array <<< "$var"`.

Comment: `test` is an existing command on linux, you should not use that name for your function.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `grades.txt` file is at the top level, but you want to run `test` under each directory.  The easiest change is to pass a full path to `$PWD/grades.txt` to the function.  Coombine that with running "cd" into each subdir.  Recommendation:

```
for FILE in students_projects/* ; do
  (cd $FILE; test $PWD/grades.txt)
done
```

Then in your "function test()", use that `$1` argument instead of grades.txt:

```
printf "..." >> $1
```